# Error in deploying locally-blockchain technology

Tags: node.js

when i tried to deploy my nodejs app (blockchain) locally, i encountered the below error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet"
npm ERR! node v4.7.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! hashtable@2.0.2 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hashtable@2.0.2 install script 'node-gyp configure build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hashtable package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hashtable
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hashtable
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'asset-diamond-demo' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --quiet' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But when i deployed it from my personal laptop at home, it got deployed.
seems to be not building at office.

can anyone suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Install `nvm` and use it to ensure you have a clean, up to date working Node setup.  Try installing Node 7.something with nvm instead of 4.